# Why is $\dim_{B}F \le n$ in $\mathbb R^n$? (Upper Bound on Minkowski–Bouligand dimension)

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, analysis

*(Please skip to the end for a word on notation)*

---

For $F \subset\mathbb R^n$, where $F\ne \varnothing$, we have $$0 \le \underline\dim_B F \le \overline\dim_B F \le n$$
and hence $$\dim_B F \le n$$
where $\dim_B F$ denotes the box-counting dimension of $F$. $\underline\dim_B F$ and $\overline\dim_B F$ denote the lower and upper box-counting dimension respectively.

---

I need help understanding the proof of the last inequality, i.e. the $\le n$ part. The proof in the book is:

> The first two inequalities are obvious; for the third, $F$ may be enclosed in a large cube $C$ so by counting $$-mesh squares $N_(F) ⩽ N_(C) ⩽ c^{−n}$ for some constant $c$.

Since $F\subset C$, $N_\delta(F) \le N_\delta(C)$ is clear. Why is $N_\delta(C) \le c\delta^{-n}$ for some $c$?

---

**Notation:**

1. About $\dim_B F$ and $N_\delta(F)$:

> The lower and upper box-counting dimensions of a subset $F$ of $ℝ^n$ are given by
> $$\underline{\dim}_B F = \underline{\lim}_{\delta\to 0} \frac{\log N_\delta(F)}{-\log \delta}$$
> $$\overline{\dim}_B F = \overline{\lim}_{\delta\to 0} \frac{\log N_\delta(F)}{-\log \delta}$$
> and the box-counting dimension of $F$ by
> $$\dim_B F = \lim_{\delta\to 0} \frac{\log N_\delta(F)}{-\log \delta}$$
> (if this limit exists), where $N_\delta(F)$ is any of the following:
>
> 1. the smallest number of sets of diameter at most $$ that cover $F$;
> 2. the smallest number of closed balls of radius $$ that cover $F$;
> 3. the smallest number of cubes of side $$ that cover $F$;
> 4. the number of $$-mesh cubes that intersect $F$;
> 5. the largest number of disjoint balls of radius $$ with centres in $F$.

2. What is a $\delta$-mesh?

> $$[m_1\delta, (m_1+1)\delta] \times [m_2\delta, (m_2+1)\delta] \times \ldots \times [m_n\delta, (m_n+1)\delta]$$ where $m_i \in\mathbb Z$ for every $1 \le i \le n$, is called a $\delta$-mesh (or a $\delta$-grid) in $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we simply enclose $F$ in a hypercube with side $s$, that cube can be broken down into $m^n$ subcubes with side $s/m$. Then we get that
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\log(m^n)}{-\log(s/m)}=n
$$
This simply says that any subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has dimension at most $n$ (which is a mathematical justification of what seems a pretty intuitive fact).

Comment: but,  why is $N_\delta(C) \le c\delta^{-n}$ for some $c$? That was my question.

Comment: Sorry, I was gone all day. Here $C$ is a cube with side $s$, $\delta=s/m$ and $N_\delta(C)=m^n$. As $m\to\infty$, $\delta\to0$. So $$\lim\limits_{\delta\to0}\frac{\log\left(N_\delta(C)\right)}{-\log(\delta)}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\log(m^n)}{-\log(s/m)}=n$$ This means that $N_\delta(C)=m^n=s^n(s/m)^{-n}=s^n\delta^{-n}$

Comment: Thank you, @robjohn! One minor follow-up question - the book also says that: "if $F\subset\mathbb R^n$ is open, then $\dim_B F = n$. Since $F$ contains a cube $C$, $N_\delta(F) \ge N_\delta(C) \ge c\delta^{-n}$ for some constant $c$ independent of $\delta$." In this case, the inequality they come up with is indeed the opposite, i.e. they say $$ N_\delta(C) \ge c\delta^{-n}$$
Could you please explain how? By the logic outlined in your answer (which I understand), we must have $ N_\delta(C) \le c\delta^{-n}$, which is the opposite of what is stated, and is of no use. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No use? What I have shown is the inequality that you asked about: "Why is $N_\delta(C) \le c\delta^{-n}$ for some $c$?" Now you are asking another question altogether: "Why does an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ have full dimension?". If you want to answer this, put a cube ***inside*** of the open set. The limits I give above are ***equalities*** and show that the dimension of the cube is $n$. Therefore, the dimension of the open set containing the cube is $n$.

Comment: Got it! Consider a cube $C$ of side $x$. Then the least number of cubes of side $\delta$ we need to cover it are $(x/\delta)^n$. Now $$\lim_{\delta\to 0} \frac{\log N_\delta(C)}{-\log\delta} = n - \lim_{\delta \to 0} \frac{n\log x}{\log\delta} = n$$
Sorry, my previous comment may have been misinterpreted. I meant it was *no use* for the *new questions about open sets*. Thanks anyway!